# Java - what is a raster and databuffer,

Tags: java, game-development

I have been learning java on and off for a while now. I’m struggling to advance past graphics and rendering images. 
I have tried to gain an understanding through the java documentation, but barely anything made sense.

If someone could explain what they mean as well as explain how to learn concepts like these independently.

Comment: I dont know - the JavaDoc seems to be great. What are you struggling with?

Comment: *but barely anything made sense* - Hard to believe. However, there are plenty of tutorials with working examples which you may find useful.

Comment: Well my main problem is just understanding databuffers and rasters for bufferedimages. There was this one line of code within this game programming tutorial I was following. It went something like this. Int[] pixels = image.getdatabufferint.getraster.getdata the image is a bufferedimage.

Comment: "is just understanding " Understanding *what* about them? What don't you understand? Not understanding often comes because you approach a topic with a preconception, and then you get confused when your preconception doesn't match with the reality. So: do you have a preconception, and in what way doesn't it match what you are reading?

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. My main confusion is what a raster and databuffer is. I know that a raster has something to with an array of pixels. But when it comes to a databuffer, I am lost. If someone could explain these to me in simple English that would be great.